# Is there a term for this bolt attachment mechanism?

Tags: bolts, hardware

We're installing Ikea cabinets in our kitchen.  The wall cabinets attach to a rail using a bolt-and-bolt-attachment-thingy that slides onto the rail, and the cabinets are then fastened to the bolts.  It seems pretty ingenious to me...and I'd like to duplicate the mechanism to solve a problem we're having.

[image: bolt and plate thing]
[image: bolt through plate thing view 1]
[image: bolt through plate thing view 2]

What I'd like is to be able to do something very similar, but using a larger bolt, and preferably a much wider plate thing, so that I can attach the plate to the bottom of the base cabinets for threading the feet onto it (the one that came with the feet isn't long enough for our very not-level floor).  So...is there a term for this?  Is there a way to recreate this with off-the-shelf (or at least the internet's shelf) parts that don't require any machining?

Comment: What I think you are referring to are commonly called "T" nuts. They are made for wood, formed metal channels and other applications. A google search may produce images that you can find at a home improvement center.

Comment: T-nut appears to have been the key search term!  A T-nut, from what I am seeing, isn't exactly what I want, but [this plate](http://www.sofalegcatalog.com/heavy-duty-screw-mounted-threaded-plate-with-m10-metric-threads-for-levelers-or-casters.html) pretty much is, which I found via a search for T-nuts.  Feel free to submit an answer I can accept.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Is it Ikea hardware? If so, go to the returns desk where they also have a huge stockpile of hardware for nearly everything they sell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think you are referring to are commonly called "T" nuts. They are made for wood, formed metal channels and other applications. A google search may produce images that you can find at a home improvement center.

Comment: I'm not seeing how t-nuts would provide a sufficiently broad flange to stabilize a leg.

Answer (score 4):

your question is "what is this thing called", and I agree that T-nut is a good answer, but when you described your application, perhaps what you're looking for could be called a ["leveling foot"](http://www.mcmaster.com/#standard-leveling-mounts/=p8yrz0).

[image: leveling foot w/ mount]

Comment: Yeah, what I was really looking for was a replacement for the plate that the foot attaches to, so I probably should have been looking at leveling feet in the first place.